# git log --since <any date prior to svn migration> shows commits from the migration date onwards, but without "--since" shows all of them

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

We've migrated from svn to git a couple of months back at March, 2019 and everything has been good since.
Now, I need to export a commit log of a specific directory in the repository and for some reason when trying to specify since when i want the logs like so :

```
    git log --first-parent master --since "01-01-2018" Directory/Subdirectory
```

Then I only get commits since March 26, 2019 (the SVN to GIT migration date) with the first commit in this log being the LAST SVN commit from that day.
I get the same result no matter what date or date format I use, as long as the date is earlier than March 26, 2019 - I will get the exact same result.

If, however - I only drop the: " --since  " part and go with:

```
    git log --first-parent master Directory/Subdirectory
```

Then I get the entire master commit log, going back to way before 2014 even, and including all of the commits that were migrated from SVN (instead of just the last one and the consequent git commit that followed)

I can export the entire log and manually remove the excess commits from the exported txt file - no problem here, but I would like to figure out why git behaves this way.
What metadata remained after the migration that causes the log to behave like this and how can I fix it.

The AuthorDate and CommitDate are identical (to each other per commit) for all commits in the master branch.
This includes the migrated svn commits - these have sequential timestamps that match their original svn commit timestamps, and the same goes for all the git commits that came after - everything is sequential and in logical order, and yet 
for some reason if adding '--since ' to the command line - it behaves as stated above (showing only commits from march 26, 2019, starting with the LAST migrated commit from svn)

If it matters this was exactly how we migrated from svn to git:

Initial clone:

```
    git svn clone http://svn.local/server/trunk RepoName --authors-file=authors.txt
```

Increments of svn commits on top of the initial clone:

```
    git svn fetch
```

Finally: merged the git-svn default migration branch to the master branch and reset --hard:

```
    git merge remotes/git-svn 
    git reset --hard
```

And finally, pushed the newly migrated git repository to its new origin server (which was blank at the time)